# Javascript Iframe Security Error Within Try/Catch Block In Webkit Browsers

Tags: javascript, iframe

When I run the following code in webkit browsers, I get an error outputted to the console despite having my code wrapped in a try/catch block.

```
var externallyFramed = false;
try {
  externallyFramed = top.location.host != location.host;
} catch (e) {
  externallyFramed = true;
}
```

The error I get is the following:

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL...**

Is there anything I can do differently to prevent the error from showing up?

Comment: Are you sure that that line is the line that generates the error?
I would think that the access-attempt is made somewhere else.

Comment: I'm positive.  I added logging to identify the line causing the error.  The line: "externallyFramed = top.location.host != location.host;" does not trigger a catchable error in webkit but does output an error to the console.